# Comparing date to NaN and undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a pretty simple if statement but I don't use javascript too much so I think I have made an error somewhere. If you go to my page you can see the value gets alerted as undefined, but a block of code still gets skipped even though the if parameters are `== undefined`. Does it matter that this is an AngularJS app?

web page: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/petType

javascript:

```
$scope.setDate = function (dateSelected) {
    alert(dateSelected);
    var now = new Date();
    $scope.latest = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());
    $scope.hoursAgo = Math.round((($scope.latest - dateSelected) / 3600000) * 100) / 100;
    if ($scope.hoursAgo === undefined || $scope.hoursAgo == NaN) {
        alert("Please choose a date/time");
    }
    else {
        alert('You lost your pet ' + $scope.hoursAgo + ' hour(s) ago');
        $scope.checkDateSet = true;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: @Liam But that question doesn't have NaN anywhere in it, and that was my main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check `if ($scope.hoursAgo === undefined || $scope.hoursAgo == NaN)`

write like this

```
if ($scope.hoursAgo === 'undefined' || isNaN($scope.hoursAgo)) {
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I can accept your answer in 5 min. Is that just an AngularJS thing or should NaN always be checked like that?

Comment: @Thomas Always in JS. Has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with your if statement. `NaN` in Javascript is somewhat special.

For example:
`NaN === NaN // false`

You can read about it more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Change your check to:

```
if ($scope.hoursAgo === undefined || isNaN($scope.hoursAgo)) {
...
} else {..}
```